# How to create hover effect on each polygon in mapbox map

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

```
function createPixelBox(jsonData){
    // a1=(x1,y2),a2=(x2,y2),a3=(x2,y1),a4=(x1,y1)

    var x,y,x1,x2,y1,y2;
    var geodata=[]; 
    var Length=jsonData.length;

          for(var i=0;i<Length;i++)
                { 

                    x=jsonData[i].latitude;
                    y=jsonData[i].longitude;
                    console.log(x+"  "+y);

                    x1 = x - 0.0045; //lower x
                    x2=  x + 0.0045; //higher x
                    y1= y - 0.0045; //lower y
                    y2= y + 0.0045; //higher y

                   geodata.push({ 
                  "type" :"Feature",
                  "properties"  : {"description": jsonData[i].ndvi,
                      "pixel":jsonData[i]
                      },

                  "geometry"       : {
                     "type": "MultiPolygon",
                         "coordinates":[ [[[x1,y2], [x2,y2], [x2,y1], [x1,y1]]]]
                                    }
                               });

                   }

       prepareMap(geodata);

  }

      var valueSelector = 'ndvi';

         function   prepareMap(mapdata){

     L.mapbox.accessToken =  'pk.eyJ1IjoiZ2F1cmF2Y2F0c3RlY2giLCJhIjoiY2l1cGo0MTl4MDAxajJ1bng5a2xieTY0diJ9.0fDXNulI91U85ngSc4jGCg';
          var mapTwo = L.mapbox.map('map-two')
          .setView(defaultLocation,defaultZoom);
       L.mapbox.styleLayer('mapbox://styles/gauravcatstech/civ82vos7008f2is5x92cpvye').addTo(mapTwo);

  var myLayer = L.mapbox.featureLayer().addTo(mapTwo);

  var zoom = mapTwo.getZoom();
   console.log("Zoom level::::"+zoom);
  var states=mapdata; 

    myLayer.setGeoJSON(states);

      myLayer.eachLayer(function(layer){

            console.log("Property in each layer");
            console.log(layer.feature.properties.pixel);

            var fillColor = "#B8B8B8"
            if (layer.feature.properties.pixel[''+valueSelector]=="38"){
              fillColor = "#ff0000";
            } else if (layer.feature.properties.pixel[''+valueSelector]<="250"){
              fillColor = "#ff3300";
            }else if ( layer.feature.properties.pixel[''+valueSelector]>="250"){
              fillColor = "#ffcc00";
            }

            layer.setStyle({
            fillColor: fillColor
                          });

                        });

          }
```

how would i apply hover effect on each polygon ....